# Copy only the required content from the text file to Excel using Python

Tags: python, spyder

I have a huge data in text file consisting of details like Date, College name, Year of Passing also it contains Name and Unique id of students as shown below. Also the text file is not formatted and it contains lot of data.

```
Group list of all the students 
5 June 2020/KCT/2015 Group BRD Rahul e34 Pradeep e44 Venkat r45 Azhar t54  
6 June 2020/BCT/2012 Group ZRD Akash e14 Pavan e24 Vipul r15 Asad t14
7 June 2020/KBN/2014 Group KRD Fairoz e45 Kumar e55 Akshay e44 Vivek e99 etc
```

When i run a python code, I need the output in a excel/csv sheet where it displays only Name (Column1) and Unique id (Column2) row by row. Basically in the excel sheet i want only names and unique ids to be displayed in Excel sheet as shown below only i need names and unique id to be displayed. I do not need other data in the excel sheet.

```
Rahul    e34 
Pradeep  e44 
Venkat   r45 
Azhar    t54
Akash    e14 
Pavan    e24 
Vipul    r15 
Asad     t14
Fairoz   e45 
Kumar    e55 
Akshay   e44 
Vivek    e99
```

This is what i have tried

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\PMishra\Desktop\Document.txt", sep='\t' )
df.to_csv('C:\Users\PMishra\Desktop\Demo.csv')
```

When i run this it will just copy all the contents from text file to excel sheet. I want output in a excel/csv sheet where it displays all Names (Column1) and Unique ids (Column2) row by row. I am new to python (Spyder). How to get only names and ids in column1 and column2 respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first row must be the name of the columns, then you can show only the two columns with the name:

```
dfnew = df[["namecolum1","namecolum1"]]

dfnew.to_csv('C:\Users\PMishra\Desktop\Demo.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load only the selected columns by calling `read_csv()` with the `usecols` argument, [see the Documentation.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
# this would load only column 0, 1, and 2
# you can use column names too: ['col0', 'col1', 'col2']
dummy_example = pandas.read_csv('path_to/your_file.csv', usecols=[0, 1, 2])
```

However, in your case I would do it without `pandas`;

```
input_file = 'path_to/input_file.txt'
output_file = 'path_to/output_file.csv'

# open both files, output in "append" mode
with open(input_file, 'r') as file, open(output_file, 'a+') as out_file:
    for line in file.readlines():

       try:
            # split at 'Group'
            line = line.split('Group')[1]

            # split and select after Group name
            line = line.split()[1:]

        except:
            # no 'Group' or no data thereafter
            # skip to the next loop 
            continue

        # create name-id pairs
        name_id = list(zip(line[2::2], line[1::2]))

        for tup in name_id:
            # make comma separated string 
            string = ','.join(tup) + '\n'

            # append to the outfile 
            out_file.write(string)
```

Output file;

```
Pradeep,e34
Venkat,e44
Azhar,r45
Pavan,e14
Vipul,e24
Asad,r15
Kumar,e45
Akshay,e55
Vivek,e44
Pradeep,e34
Venkat,e44
Azhar,r45
Pavan,e14
Vipul,e24
Asad,r15
Kumar,e45
Akshay,e55
Vivek,e44
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, its working when the text fil contains data as shown above, actually my data is huge. When i run with that i get error as       `line = line.split('Group')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I am trying hard to fix the error, i am unable to fix it. . I request you to please help.

Comment: I am new to python and facing the issue, i hope you willl help me fix the problem. When i run that code with actual text file i get the error. `line = line.split('Group')[1] IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I updated my answer and you marked the other answer as the answer you are looking for...

Comment: i am getting error    `except:
           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`